# How to self destruct an object in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, object, delegates

My object finish their job. He have the control of work flow, but now it have to call a function in the object that create it and have to be released. The problem is like this:

```
AnObject *object;
- (void)function 
{
     object = [[AnObject alloc] init];
     [object doYourJob];
     //The program continue to run next line, it don't stop here. So, I can't send a [object release] here
}

- (void)callThisWhenFinish
{
 //do something
 //can't call [object release] because it is in the stack and run a line of a released object
}
```

So, how can I release the memory of object, I try this:

- Send a `[object release]` in `callThisWhenFinish` or in `function`. - Fail! The program still have to run some lines of `AnObject`.
- Use delegate way to run `callThisWhenFinish`. -  Fail! I cant release `AnObject` because it try to run the next line when the function `callThisWhenfinish` finish.
- Use a NSNotificationCenter to post a notification to `callThisWhenFinish`. Fail! When I post notification it immediate call the `callThisWhenFinish` and `AnObject` can run the next line and it is release, causing a crash.
- Use the same NSNotificationCenter with a delay on it. How safe is this way? How can I know that `AnObject` will not be called again?
- Use the [object autorelease]. This work, but I don't know when it is done. My `AnObject` use a lot of RAM and have to be free as fast as possible.

Any other idea?

Comment: make it an instance variable.

Comment: Is that `AnObject *object;` actually supposed to be a global?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your object is doing background work, it is a good idea to have it retain itself during that time. That way, you don't have to worry about it being deallocated until it is done. Your `function` method can safely release it after starting the action, but it won't be deallocated until it is ready to be.

```
AnObject *object;
- (void)function {
    object = [[AnObject alloc] init];
    [object doYourJob];
    [object release];
}
- (void)callThisWhenFinish {
    //do something
}
```

In AnObject:

```
- (void)doYourJob {
    [self retain];
    // enter background and call backgroundMethod
}
- (void)backgroundMethod {
    // This is the method which doYourJob calls in the background to do the work
    // Do some work
    [delegate callThisWhenFinish];
    // do whatever else needs to be done
    [self release];
}
```

Comment: How do we do this with ARC today?

Comment: @Thomas You could use an instance variable for its strong reference, assigning `self` to it when starting the task and assigning `nil` to it when done. Additionally, some methods of executing in the background automatically retain the target object, such as NSThread, so you could just use them.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't make it an ivar, why not something like this:

```
 - (void)callThisWhenFinishAndRelease:(id)obj
```

Then you have a pointer to it.